# Load related entity for each entity in a related collection

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

```
public class Parent
{
   public IList<Child> Collection { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   public GrandChild GrandChild { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

Context.Parents.Select(p => new { Parent = p, Collection = p.Collection } );
```

The query gets me the collection for every parent. But how do I load the GrandChild for every Child in each collection?

Answer (score 0):

Just append another .Select to the end of the parent .Select

Comment: Off the top of my head it is something like this: context.Parents.Include(c => c.Child.Select(g => g.GrandChild))

Comment: Also, where have you setup your relationships (navigation properties) between the entities? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: Look again... a parent doesn't have a child. It has a collection of childs.

Comment: Yes, I know it has a collection of child. A one to many relationship. Where have you setup the one-to-many relationships?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. This is from Code First so just declaring the collection is setting up the relationship.